# How to ensure the Blazor renderer recognises a collection change

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

As part of a content management page I have an image library editor, which displays a list of images and allows the user to add and remove images. This is Blazor server side.

There is an InputFile button connected to an ImageUpload function, which re-acquires the list of images after an update. The list is bound to a `List<ImageItemViewModel> ImageList` , just an `@foreach` in a div. Once the ImageUpload function is complete, it asks the server API for the current image list and does:

1. `ImageList.Clear()`
2. ...get the images via API and does some processing, resulting in some viewmodels...
3. `ImageList.AddRange(...image view models...)`

Now, what happens is that step 1 clears the list, visually - you get an empty list. (In hindsight, I recognise that this is something I would not want anyway)
But step 3 does not result in a UI update.

To solve it, what I did was define a local variable , tempList, that is initially empty, populate that in step 2,  then I set ImageList to the tempList. This is what I should have been doing in the first place, as I now see that the Clear() method would have caused a brief flicker had the AddRange worked.

However, if I had wanted that behaviour,  what is the correct pattern or what mechanisms exist in Blazor server side to get the UI to update when a collection or list has changed? Are we supposed to be using Observables here, or is there some command available like a NoticeUpdate(ref var) or something?

Comment: Provide the code, best is a [mre]. What you describe should not normally happen.

Comment: I'm guessing, but you're probably using a Blazor event handler method that returns a void and runs async code (your image list handling).  On the first yield in your method, control gets handed back to the Blazor Event Handler.  Without a Task to wait on it runs to completion, running a `StateHasChanged`.  The list is clear at this point.  If this is the case change your event handler to return a `Task`.  If this answers your question I'll add it as an answer with some more detail.  As it's only a guess, I'll not adding it now.

Comment: Trying to do a repro, and curiously the minimum project does not have the error. I suspect it's something to do with async so I am dicking around with the repro now to see if I can simulate things. Gut feel is giving me a similar conclusion , Shaun...let me check and get back to you shortly.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Actually I am giving up on building the repro as I remember now the event handler (UploadImage) that eventually results in calling the GetImageLibrary had an error where the call was missing an await. That had to have been the problem. Feel free to add an answer , I will mark it as correct answer. They were all async Tasks, no voids, but the lack of await would have fit your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing, but you're probably using a Blazor event handler method that returns a void (or there's a sub method that does something similar). Your image handling code almost certainly runs async code.  On the first yield, control is handed back. Without a Task to wait on it runs to completion, running StateHasChanged. The list is clear at this point.

#### Update

From comments it would appear that you have an async method within the code path that doesn't get awaited.  Same result.  The handler may return a task, but with an "un-awaited" async task in the code path, at first yield, parent code blocks run to completion, `Tasks` complete and the event handler completes.

The Blazor event handler code looks like this:

```
var task = InvokeAsync(EventMethod);
StateHasChanged();
if (!task.IsCompleted)
{
    await task;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

If `EventMethod` only contains synchronous code, it runs to completion and `StateHasChanged` is called once.  If `EventMethod` returns a running task, it calls `StateHasChanged` on first yield, and then on completion.

Comment: You da man. Cheers.